# How to find the values of constants when there is one stationary point, no stationary point, and determining the maximum number os stationary points.

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

[image][image]

- b) values of x is when f'(x) = 0
- c) how do i solve this without using common sense and knowing that if
  a=0 there will be no turning points/inflections
- d)how do i solve this?
- e) max number of stationary points is always = total number of
  intercepts?? therefore 2... im not sure about this one, i remember
  some rule about this (vaguely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) $$f(x) = \frac{1}{27}({ax-1})^3(b-3x)+1$$

has the derivate

$$\frac{1}{27}(3a({ax-1})^2(b-3x)-3({ax-1})^3)=\frac{1}{27}(ax-1)^2(3ab-9ax-3ax+3)$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}(ax-1)^2(ab-4ax+1)$$

So, f '(x) = 0 implies $x=\frac{1}{a}$ or $x=\frac{ab+1}{4a}$ for $a\ne 0$

c) For a = 0, the derivate is $\frac{1}{9}$ for all real x, so there is no stationary
   point.

d) Since f '(x) has at most two roots, f '(x) has at most 2 stationary points.

Comment: so when the denominator of a f'(x) is undefined that is when there an no stationary points?

Comment: The derivate can be calculated using the chain rule for $({ax-1})^3$ and the product rule.

Comment: what about ONE stationary point? how do u find the values...

Comment: Simply set $\frac{1}{a}=\frac{ab+1}{4a}$. You get the condition ab=3.

Comment: but why is this so? i dont understand the reasoning. im a bit lost here.

Comment: A stationary point of a function is a point with an x-value with the property f '(x)=0. We found out, that there are two possible points, which might be identical. So, depending on a,b, we can have no, one or two stationary points.

Comment: so for 2 stationary points would 1/a have to not equal ab+1/4a ? ... how would u solve for 2, just curious.

Comment: Yes,Exactly that. But note that it must be (ab+1)/(4a) (You missed the parantheses)

Comment: if we knew one stationary point was at (1,1) how would we find the other?

Comment: x=1 so 1/a=1 therefore a=1 then we sub a=1 in the other equation. but we get (b+1)/4 for second sp.

Comment: Either $\frac{1}{a}=1$ or $\frac{ab+1}{4a}=1$. So either a=1 (The other x-value is $\frac{b+1}{4}$) or ab+1=4a in which case we cannot determine the other x-value, since we do not know a.

Comment: thank you much peter! great help